# How to create subcategories on website?

Tags: html

I want to create subcategories on my website, I know I can just save files within folders, such as:

http://www.mysite.com/category/content.html

but how can I allow a user to go to the following page?

http://www.mysite.com/category/

Any advise would be much appreciated as I'm really stumped!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on server configuration, but usually you just create `/category/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set default page for each sub directory (usually it is index.html, but you can set your own). It is done in your server configuration.

You can also consider URLrewriting so that URLs doesn't have to match physical content on the server

Comment: So I put an index.html file in the folder where I want the url to be displayed in browswer as mysite.com/myfolder/  ? Is that what you mean? Would removing the .html using htaccessdisplay the above URL?

Comment: By the way, thanks so much for your response, I really appreciate it!

Comment: at least in iis it's that way, if you have default page for each directory, you can have url without file you're requesting - you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

For directory (or folder) URI's your webserver may do one of two things: it will either list the files and subfolders within that directory, **or** will look for a default page to return: usually this is "index.html" or possibly "home.html" or something similar.

If you check your webserver's config file the behaviour (list contents or default page) and, in the case of default page, which page is returned will be specified. You will also be able to over-ride this and specify someother default page if you like.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Should I use .htaccess to prevent the browser showing mysite.com/myfolder/index.html and isntead force it to display mysite.com/myfolder/

Answer (score 0):

Your web server will in most cases be configured to return a default page when you enter the folder. Usually this is index.html.

So if you put index.html (or other default filename) in the http://www.mysite.com/category/ folder your users will see the page.